# Problem Starting Login Shell in Cygwin xterm

Tags: bash, cygwin, zsh, xterm

I am trying to start a login shell within xterm in Cygwin.  I am able to start a regular shell no problem.  Here is what happens:

```
C:\Users\sridhar>C:\cygwin\bin\xterm -display :0 /bin/bash

C:\Users\sridhar>REM bash starts normally.

C:\Users\sridhar>C:\cygwin\bin\xterm -display :0 /bin/bash -l
/usr/bin/xterm: cannot open /dev/null: 17:File exists

C:\Users\sridhar>REM bash starts as a non-login shell.

C:\Users\sridhar>C:\cygwin\bin\xterm -display :0 /bin/zsh

C:\Users\sridhar>REM zsh starts normally.

C:\Users\sridhar>C:\cygwin\bin\xterm -display :0 /bin/zsh -l
/usr/bin/xterm: cannot open /dev/null: 17:File exists

C:\Users\sridhar>REM zsh starts as a non-login shell.

C:\Users\sridhar>
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: have you started the X server ?

Comment: Yes.  Like I said, the Xterm windows start normally when not specified with `-l`.  In fact, **an** Xterm window starts even **with** `-l`, but gives the error and doesn't start as a login shell.

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate your issue. However, I suspect that /dev/null is a regular file on your Cygwin installation, rather than a device file. You should be able to see that by doing an `ls -l /dev` and compare what you see for `null` with other devices. I think that if it's not a device file, that you can delete it and it will be recreated the next time you start Cygwin.